# How to create well formatted HTML code and getting the expected result

Tags: html, formatting

If you want to format your HTML code neatly, e.g.

```
<div>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

there will be white-space between the links when the page is rendered..
How can I format my code like this and get rid of the unwanted spaces between the links?

Another thing. If youre using JavaScript and there is an onclick on the first link, the next sibling will be a whitespace, not a link.
How to do this with a nice compromise?

Comment: I don't quiet understand... I might just be reading it wrong. Can you should the output so I know what you are talking about? Are you trying to get rid of the white space?

Comment: I think the OP's point is that clear HTML can result in unwanted whitespace in the rendering. See http://jsfiddle.net/7ZMLT/

Comment: yes. And in this example mind the paradox